# How to search in Google Scholar within a particular conference?

Tags: conference, literature-search, google-scholar

Using Google's search operators, [guide](https://bynd.com/news-ideas/google-advanced-search-comprehensive-list-google-search-operators/), we can restrict our search to that of a particular web domain, eg: `site:twitter.com Paul Daniels`

Within Google Scholar, can we perform a similar in nature search but for articles within a particular conference (or journal)? I am looking an operator specific to Google scholar which I expect would resemble `conference:NIPS Paul Daniels`

Comment: if you are in a computer science related discipline, much easier to use DBLP.

Answer (score 17):

To search within a particular conference, open the navigation menu on the Google Scholar start page, using the hamburger button (☰) on the top left, and click on "Advanced search". This will open an extended search dialog where a field "Return articles published in..." exists.

Comment: It doesn't appear this feature still exists in Apr 2021

Comment: Where is this 'triangle'? Can't see it.

Comment: @NathanB Thanks for the question. It turns out that my answer was outdated. I have now updated it.

Answer (score 15):

You can use the `source:` operator. For example, search by `source:NIPS` to restrict  to documents published by sources containing "NIPS" in their name.

Comment: This operator does not appear to work in Apr 2021

Comment: @DanielKats Strange, it still works fine for me. Note that Scholar is sometimes very picky: Sometimes you have to use the source's abbreviation and sometimes you have to write it out in full. Either way, for me writing `source:NIPS` gives me results that all have `NIPS` highlighted in the source field (next to the author).

Comment: You're right. It appears you **must not** have a space after "source:" for this method to work

Comment: Better do: `search terms source:NIPS OR source:"Neural Information"`

Comment: Yes, good point. Google Scholar doesn't use abbreviations consistently in the source field, and does not match the full name if you write the abbreviation.

Comment: If I want to search a paper that was published in *any* conference (but not only on Arxiv) - how can I do that?

Comment: @NathanB In that case you can add a minus in front of the search term to exclude it, as in `-source:arxiv`.

Answer (score 4):

From the main [scholar.google.com](http://scholar.google.com) page you can select "Advanced Search" from the menu on the top left side (hidden behind hamburger menu button)

Comment: This feature does not appear to be present in Apr 2021

Answer (score 2):

### Search by site

When we search for a keyword, on the right side of the search results we get for each entry something like `[PDF] acm.org`. This is useful to find the websites you'd like to add.

We can combine these sites: `memory site:ieee.org OR site:acm.org OR site:usenix.org`

### Search by source

The search results have the name of the conference below the title of each entry. This might be a full title instead of only an acronym and that's what you need to use.

For example, `attack source:ASPLOS` returns nothing. But we get results using `attack source:"Architectural Support for Programming Languages and Operating Systems"`.

Using a more broader term for source such as `attack source:"Operating Systems"` gives you results for multiple conferences, namely ASPLOS and SOSP because both have *operating systems* in their name.

Comment: Even better: `source:ASPLOS OR source:"Architectural Support for Programming Languages and Operating Systems"`

Answer (score 1):

A complimentary, programmatic approach to all of the all great answers above using Python and [Google Scholar Organic Results API](https://serpapi.com/google-scholar-organic-results) from SerpApi.

It's a paid API with a free plan that bypasses blocks from Google and does all the hard lifting so the end-user only needs to think about what data to extract.

Code and [example in the online IDE](https://replit.com/@DimitryZub1/how-to-search-in-google-scholar-within-a-particular-confere#main.py) to extract data from all pages:

```
import os, json
from serpapi import GoogleSearch
from urllib.parse import urlsplit, parse_qsl

params = {
    "api_key": os.getenv("API_KEY"), # your serpapi API key
    "engine": "google_scholar",     
    "q": "AI source:NIPS",        # search query
    "hl": "en",                   # language
    # "as_ylo": "2017",           # from 2017
    # "as_yhi": "2021",           # to 2021
    "start": "0"                  # first page
    }

search = GoogleSearch(params)

organic_results_data = []

papers_is_present = True
while papers_is_present:
    results = search.get_dict()

    print(f"Currently extracting page №{results.get('serpapi_pagination', {}).get('current')}..")

    for result in results["organic_results"]:
        position = result["position"]
        title = result["title"]
        publication_info_summary = result["publication_info"]["summary"]
        result_id = result["result_id"]
        link = result.get("link")
        result_type = result.get("type")
        snippet = result.get("snippet")

        organic_results_data.append({
            "page_number": results.get("serpapi_pagination", {}).get("current"),
            "position": position + 1,
            "result_type": result_type,
            "title": title,
            "link": link,
            "result_id": result_id,
            "publication_info_summary": publication_info_summary,
            "snippet": snippet,
            })

        if "next" in results.get("serpapi_pagination", {}):
            search.params_dict.update(dict(parse_qsl(urlsplit(results["serpapi_pagination"]["next"]).query)))
        else:
            papers_is_present = False

print(json.dumps(organic_results_data, indent=2, ensure_ascii=False))
```

Part of the output:

```
[
  {
    "page_number": 1,
    "position": 1,
    "result_type": "Pdf",
    "title": "Nuts and bolts of building AI applications using Deep Learning",
    "link": "https://media.nips.cc/Conferences/2016/Slides/6203-Slides.pdf",
    "result_id": "-x2la-_xce0J",
    "publication_info_summary": "A Ng - NIPS Keynote Talk, 2016 - media.nips.cc",
    "snippet": "Given the safety-critical requirement of autonomous driving and thus the need for extremely high levels of accuracy, a pure end-to-end approach is still challenging to get to work. End-…"
  }, ... other results
]
```

---

Custom solution:

```
from parsel import Selector
import requests, json, os


def scrape_conference_publications(query: str, source: list[str]):
    if source:
    
        # source:NIPS OR source:Neural Information
        sources = " OR ".join([f'source:{item}' for item in source]) 
            
        # https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#passing-parameters-in-urls
        params = {
            "q": f'{query.lower()} {sources}',  # search query
            "hl": "en",                         # language of the search
            "gl": "us"                          # country of the search
        }

        # https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#custom-headers
        headers = {
            "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/100.0.4896.127 Safari/537.36"
        }

        html = requests.get("https://scholar.google.com/scholar", params=params, headers=headers, timeout=30)
        selector = Selector(html.text)
        
        publications = []
        
        for result in selector.css(".gs_r.gs_scl"):
            title = result.css(".gs_rt").xpath("normalize-space()").get()
            link = result.css(".gs_rt a::attr(href)").get()
            result_id = result.attrib["data-cid"]
            snippet = result.css(".gs_rs::text").get()
            publication_info = result.css(".gs_a").xpath("normalize-space()").get()
            cite_by_link = f'https://scholar.google.com/scholar{result.css(".gs_or_btn.gs_nph+ a::attr(href)").get()}'
            all_versions_link = f'https://scholar.google.com/scholar{result.css("a~ a+ .gs_nph::attr(href)").get()}'
            related_articles_link = f'https://scholar.google.com/scholar{result.css("a:nth-child(4)::attr(href)").get()}'
            pdf_file_title = result.css(".gs_or_ggsm a").xpath("normalize-space()").get()
            pdf_file_link = result.css(".gs_or_ggsm a::attr(href)").get()
        
            publications.append({
                "result_id": result_id,
                "title": title,
                "link": link,
                "snippet": snippet,
                "publication_info": publication_info,
                "cite_by_link": cite_by_link,
                "all_versions_link": all_versions_link,
                "related_articles_link": related_articles_link,
                "pdf": {
                    "title": pdf_file_title,
                    "link": pdf_file_link
                }
            })
        
        # or return publications instead
        # return publications
    
        print(json.dumps(publications, indent=2, ensure_ascii=False))


scrape_conference_publications(query="anatomy", source=["NIPS", "Neural Information"])
```

Outputs:

```
[
  {
    "result_id": "hjgaRkq_oOEJ",
    "title": "Differential representation of arm movement direction in relation to cortical anatomy and function",
    "link": "https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1741-2560/6/1/016006/meta",
    "snippet": "… ",
    "publication_info": "T Ball, A Schulze-Bonhage, A Aertsen… - Journal of neural …, 2009 - iopscience.iop.org",
    "cite_by_link": "https://scholar.google.com/scholar/scholar?cites=16258204980532099206&as_sdt=2005&sciodt=0,5&hl=en",
    "all_versions_link": "https://scholar.google.com/scholar/scholar?cluster=16258204980532099206&hl=en&as_sdt=0,5",
    "related_articles_link": "https://scholar.google.com/scholar/scholar?q=related:hjgaRkq_oOEJ:scholar.google.com/&scioq=anatomy+source:NIPS+OR+source:Neural+Information&hl=en&as_sdt=0,5",
    "pdf": {
      "title": "[PDF] psu.edu",
      "link": "http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.324.1523&rep=rep1&type=pdf"
    }
  }, ... other results
]
```

You can also have a look at a dedicated, step-by-step blog post [Scrape Google Scholar Papers within a particular conference in Python](https://serpapi.com/blog/scrape-google-scholar-papers-within-a-particular-conference-in-python/) at SerpApi just about it.

> Disclaimer, I work for SerpApi.